# Assigning values to char array sublists in java

Tags: java, arrays

How could I assign a int value to each of the sublists in the multidimensional char array

```
    public int getScore(String Input)
    {
        /* Initial score is 0 but then will increase based on letter value*/
        int totalScore = 0;
        /* Takes countryInput value and converts it to a character array*/
        char[] word = Input.toCharArray();

        /* Grouped letters together based on point values */
       char[][] letters = {{'a','e','i','o','u','l','n','s','t','r'},{'d','g'},
           {'b','c','m','p'},{'f','h','v','w','y'},{'k'},{'j','x'},{'q','z'}};


        return totalScore;
    }
```

Comment: can you give a test case?

Comment: Why not use a `HashMap` since all the letters you seem to use are unique and assign each letter (key) a corresponding value.

Comment: @TongChen Say I put in the word America, it should break it up into a char array 'a', 'm' and so on. The letters should then be matched up with the rows and assigned a point value based on that

Comment: @Sudheesh Singanamalla I have to do what the book says I can do:(

Comment: your question is not so clear what your expectation is!!. but after several reading I understand that your are looking an integer value for inserted string after converting into array with respect of alphabet from another array which store alphabet value.

Comment: If you are flexible in storing char[][] letters in Map, this can be done using multiple ways depending on what you want to keep as a Key the point value or the letter. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, if you are flexible in storing char[][] letters in Map, one of the ways could be -

```
public int getScore(String input)
    {
        /* Initial score is 0 but then will increase based on letter value*/
        int totalScore = 0;

        /* Takes countryInput value and converts it to a character array*/
        char[] word = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        /* Grouped letters together based on point values */
       //char[][] letters = {{'a','e','i','o','u','l','n','s','t','r'},{'d','g'},
       //    {'b','c','m','p'},{'f','h','v','w','y'},{'k'},{'j','x'},{'q','z'}};

       /*Store letters grouping in map with their value as Key*/
       Map<Integer, List<Character>> letters =  new HashMap<>();
       letters.put(1, Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u','l','n','s','t','r'));
       letters.put(2, Arrays.asList('d','g'));
       letters.put(3, Arrays.asList('b','c','m','p'));
       letters.put(4, Arrays.asList('f','h','v','w','y'));
       letters.put(5, Arrays.asList('k'));
       letters.put(6, Arrays.asList('j','x'));
       letters.put(7, Arrays.asList('q','z'));

       for(char ch: word) {
           for(Entry<Integer, List<Character>> entrySet : letters.entrySet()) {
               if(entrySet.getValue().contains(ch)) {
                   totalScore += entrySet.getKey();
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       return totalScore;
    }
```

Other way round, you can store the letters as key and their point value as value in map like this -

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('a',1);
.
.
.
map.put('z',7);
```

then you logic will be simplified a lot -

```
for(char ch: word) {
    totalScore += map.get(char);
}
```

and you are done.

Comment: No problem. :-)